# Utility of managed=False option in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

In django models we have option named **managed** which can be set `True` or `False`

According to documentation the only difference this option makes is whether table will be managed by django or not. Is management by django or by us makes any difference?

Is there any pros and cons of using one option rather than other?

I mean why would we opt for `managed=False`? Will it give some extra control or power which affects my code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The main reason for using `managed=False` is if your model is backed by something like a database view, instead of a table - so you don't want Django to issue `CREATE TABLE` commands when you run `syncdb`.

Answer (score 16):

Right from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed):

> `managed=False` is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when `managed=False`. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal

Comment: I have a legacy database that I have set to managed=False. But I still want to create new tables in that db and new fields in already existing tables. What should I use? If i use managed=False, it wouldn't create new fields.

Comment: @MazharAli Maybe you don't need the `managed=False` parameter? If you remove it, does anything break? If not, just remove it :)

If you have a more complicated case, I suggest you create a new question on SO.

Comment: Yeah I got it. I had to set managed=True and then fake the initial migration so the tables won't be created. And now only the new tables or fields are created.

Answer (score 11):

When ever we create the django model, the **managed=True** implicitly is
true by default. As we know that when we run `python manage.py makemigrations` the migration file(which we can say a db view) is
created in migration folder of the app and to apply that migration i.e
creates the table in db or we can say schema.

So by **managed=False**, we restrict Django to create table(scheme, update
the schema of the table) of that model or its fields specified in
migration file.

Why we use its?

case1: Sometime we use two db for the project for
example we have db1(default) and db2, so we don't want particular
model to be create the schema or table in db1 so we can this or we can
customize the db view.

case2.  In django ORM, the db table is tied to django ORM model, It
help tie a database view to bind with a django ORM model.

Can also go through the [link](https://blog.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/):

We can add our raw sql for db view in migration file.

The raw sql in migration look like: In 0001_initial.py

from **future** import unicode_literals

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW app_test AS 
    SELECT row_number() OVER () as id,
        ci.user_id,
        ci.company_id,

),
    ]
```

**Above code is just for overview of the looking of the migration file, can go through above link for brief.**